# How do I limit floating point output to three decimal places in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to know how to do this operation in bash script or command.

```
Memory=5.69157005392596529692500193779136 %
```

I want the output in unix script like

```
Memory=5.691 %
```

How to get that value?

Comment: Read `man bash` about `printf`. Read `man printf` about format specifiers. Try `printf "%6.3d" $Memory`.

Comment: @DastageerUmar you should not try it, because it doesn't work. bash doesn't support floating point numbers, and the "precision" part makes no sense with the `d` (integer) printf specifier. If you have to do that in bash, you could just treat `Memory` as a string: `mem=5.6915700539259652969250019377913; printf '%s.%.3s\n' "${mem%.*}" "${mem#*.}"`

Comment: Notice that in a language with floating point numbers like C, awk, perl, etc, `printf("%.3f",` or `"%.4g"` would round that number to `5.692`, not to `5.691`.

Comment: printf '%s.%.3s\n' "${mem%.*}" "${mem#*.}" - is working fine.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that the `%s.%.3s` will **truncate** to 3 decimal places, not round, i.e. `5.691` when it really should be `5.692`